Doubt regarding the prime counting function $\pi(n)$

Can we prove that $$\pi(n^2)-\pi\! \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{n^2}{2}\right  \rfloor \right)>n$$
when $n \geq 11?$

I found this when I was solving a problem where whether a $n\times n$ grid of numbers can be filled from $\{1,2,\cdots,n^2\}$ so that the set of products of columns is equal to that of the rows. I could make a Python program where the program spits out a matrix of such desired numbers. The program could find such matrix till $n=10,$ but the system broke when $n\geq 11.$ I discovered that such matrices can't be formed when the above equation holds. But can we prove this? I have no idea how to do this. I considered approximating $\pi(n)$ as $n/\ln n$, but it did not beget anything useful. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Yes, it can be proved by using estimates on $\pi(n)$. See this post, for some ideas on such estimates (perhaps there are better posts): $\pi(n^2)-\pi(n^2/2) \geq \frac{n^2}{\ln{n}}(0.5-1.25506/3.5)$

You may use the bounds $\frac{x}{\log x}\lt \pi(x)\lt \frac{3x}{2\log x}$ for $x\geq 17$. It follows $\pi(n^2)-\pi\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2}\right\rfloor\right) \gt \frac{n^2}{2\log n} - \frac{3n^2}{4\log(n^2/2)}$ for $n\geq 17$. For $n>43$ this bound is tight enough to show that the required quantity is $\gt n$. Till $n\le 43$ one may check via computation.

But can you prove specifically that it is greater than 11?

For $n=10$ is is equal to $n$, i.e.,$\pi(n^2)-\pi\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2}\right\rfloor\right) =25-15=10=n$,  and for $43\ge n\ge 11$ it is $>n$, by a direct computation (use the known values for small $n$).
